# Кастомный выпадающий список для вариативной позиции товара Woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

занимаюсь арендой игр (каждая из которых имеет аккаунт) и мне необходимо сортировать их на уровне вариаций. Потому как одна игра, условно Spider Man имеет 40 аккаунтов, где каждый из аккаунтов имеет от трёх до семи вариаций. Как раз таки эти вариации хочу подписывать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На woocommerce в админ-панели для вариативных товаров хочу добавить функцию выбора числа от 1 до 70-ти как это показано на скриншоте. И сортировать варианты от одного аккаунта под цифрой 1, другие условно 6 вариаций под другим числом... Есть у кого-то решение или совет?

Comment: Во первых никогда не трогай родные фалы плагинов. Во  вторых код нужно показывать кодом, а не картинками. (но совершено не нужно показывать код стандартных файлов WP/WC - те кто смогут помочь и так смогут их увидеть.) И в главных - исправь вопрос и внятно опиши какую задачу пытаешься решить.